# Meshlab: I can`t use the poisson filter

Tags: 3d, scanning, meshlab

What I´m trying to do is: from a point cloud, Iwant to get a solid object. For that reason I use the program "Meshlab".

In that program I load the point cloud and when I try to apply the filter "Screened Poisson Surface Reconstrucction", it says:

"Filter requires correct per vertex normals.
If you encounter this error on a triangulated mesh try to use the Remove Unrefereenced Vertices filter.
Enabling the cleaning option also work.".

The thing is that when I aply that filter all the points dissapear.

Can you help me?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to this game too.  But... heres how you do it:

1. import your pointcloud
2. **filters> remeshing simplifications reconstructions> compute face normals**
3. filters> remeshing simplifications reconstructions> screened poisson surface reconstructions

This is the bare minimum.  Youtube does a good job of how to clean up your surface you create, however most uses another file format and does not go into how to get your data in from a point cloud.